# adding height to rails search field tag

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am having trouble styling the height of a rails search_field_tag, nothing I do seems to change the actual height of the input box, I know this can be done but I am running into a wall, thanks in advance!

ERB:

```
<%= form_tag spree.products_path, method: :get, id: 'top-search-form',  do %>
  <%= search_field_tag :keywords, params[:keywords], id:'search_field', size: 15, maxlength: 128, placeholder: "Search" %>
  <%= submit_tag t(:search), class: 'search_b', name: nil, value: '' %>
<% end %>
```

css

```
.search_field {
    background: url(<%= asset_path 'store/bg_search.png' %>) no-repeat;
    float: left;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 7px 0 0 15px;
}

input#search_field {
    border: 0 none;
    width: 147px;
    font-style: normal;
    background-color:transparent;
    margin-top:-4px;
    color: #454545;
    float: left;
}

input.search_b,
input.search_b:hover {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use text_field  tag instead. See the screenshot

```
<%=text_field_tag :age, value = nil, options = {style:"height:100px;border-radius:25px;", placeholder:"search"}%>
```

search_field_tag has the same parameters as text_field tag

as   http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag says options can accept other params "Any other key creates standard HTML attributes for the tag."

**upd**
dhaile is right. You don't actually have height in your **input#search_field** selector.

[image]

Comment: hm I also tried this, and it actually made generated two input fields and I can't seem to figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

`<%= form_tag spree.products_path, method: :get, id: 'top-search-form',  do %>`
 has  trailing comma, remove that: 
  `<%= form_tag spree.products_path, method: :get, id: 'top-search-form'  do %>` and try it, it worked for me with this customized SCSS:

```
form#top-search-form{ height:5em;
    input#search_field{height:4em;
    }
```

}

Comment: hmm, it doesnt seem to affect the height of the input field

Answer (score 1):

In CSS you using class .search_field{...} but I didn't see that class in ERB. Maybe you can try change height or padding that field.

Answer (score 0):

<%= text_field_tag :q, '', size: 8, style:"font-size:1.0em" %>  should work 'options = " not needed.

The "style:"font-size:1.0em" code becomes an HTML option. The 'options = " that preceded the word style is NOT needed. You can use any allowable HTML font-size option you like by em, ,small, large, %, px etc.

If you leave 'options = ' in the code will then be ignored by Rails.